# Create spring prototype beans from application properties

Tags: java, spring, prototype, javabeans, autowired

I want to create N beans based on a list of values defined in application.properties

e.g.

```
MyBean {
    private String name; // with appropriate accessor methods
    MyBean(String n) {
        this.name = n;
    }
    public void saySomeThing() {
        log.debug(this.name+ " says hello");
    }
}
```

I would have a list in application.properties as

```
names[0]=James
names[1]=Mark
```

How do I create beans (in this case, 2) and then use them arbitrarily when required?
e.g.

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    if (i%2==0)
        //get James to say hello
    else 
        //get Mark to say hello
}
```

BTW. I intend to use annotations.

Comment: I would implement this with an kind of factory.

Comment: Thanks. How do you recommend i configure the name from the config file? Also, how bout usage? In my use case, I want to create N beans and then reuse them later (like in the for loop.).

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this with an kind of factory.

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public MyBean myBean() {
    String name = ...
    return new MyBean(name);
}
```

Comment: Implemented kinda awkward solution. Created a config class which captures all names (from application.properties) as an Array. Then used a  Factory  to iterate over the array and create beans using context.getBean("myBean").